# Autocreating new node based on non-existing node reference

Tags: 7, ajax, nodes

Are there pre-existing modules compatible with drupal 7 that let me autocreate a new node when I enter a value into an autocomplete node reference field that doesn't exist? Sort of like with taxonomy, but with node references instead. The new content is based on what's on the form only there's no need for a separate page to show up to fill in more details. I was wondering if there's something that does this, I'm aware that I could just create a simple module with a hook on node_insert to do this but I was wondering if I could leverage something that already exists.

Comment: What is autocomplete going to autocomplete if it doesn't exist yet?  Do you want your form to change information in a node if it does autocomplete to, say, the title of an existing node, but create a new node if  no node with such a title exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Reference Create](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate) module.

It will create the node automatically without having to fill in the node fields.